# Create random numbers

Tags: c, random

this is my first question here, i'm making a little game, and for assigning the roles, i need random numbers. I have this code, but is possible that the numbers don't be repeated? Thanks.

```
void giveroles() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand() % i + 1; 
    switch ( r ) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: In linux system you can also read `/dev/randdom`

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Which might take a *long* time if your system has not enough entropy. Use /dev/urandom for faster albeit possibly not so random numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to randomly assign a small set of numbers, rather than generate them at random, create a list of the numbers you want, and then randomise the order of the list (iterate over the list, randomly swapping entries).

For example:

```
int cards[52];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 52 ; i++)
{
    cards[i] = i;
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++)
{
    int r1 = rand()%52;
    int r2 = rand()%52;
    int t = cards[r1];
    cards[r1] = cards[r2];
    cards[r2] = t;
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < 52 ; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", cards[i]);
}
```

For completeness, it has been pointed out that shuffling in this fashion is biased. Here's a variation which should be unbiased:

```
cards[0] = 0;
for(int i = 1 ; i < 52 ; i++)
{
    int r = rand() % (i+1);
    cards[i] = cards[r];
    cards[r] = i;
}
```

(it should be further noted that taking the module of rand() is also likely to be biased, as the range of rand() will not be an even multiple)

Comment: Thank you @JasonD, i just tried something similar and worked :P

Comment: Shuffling is a good idea, but this shuffle will lead to biased output -- not all arrangements will be equally likely.  Try the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) which also allows one to initialize the array _while shuffling_.

Comment: true, and `rand()%x` is also biased. I suspect it doesn't matter too much here though.

Answer (score 3):

Take out the line `srand(time(NULL));`. You should in general only ever do this once in your program, e.g. at the start of `main()`, in order to randomize the seed used by subsequent calls to `rand()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to repeat random numbers, the solution is to keep track of which random numbers you have previously used, and if you get a "hit" in your list of existing numbers, try again.

Also, using `srand(time(NULL));` should only be done once. I suspect this is more the question you were actually asking.