# Assigning char to int

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, poker

I'm making a poker game, and i have the shuffle function (based in other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010916/create-random-numbers)).
Now my problem is, how can i assign the name of the card to each number of the array, for example i want **cartas[3] = "J spades"**.

I thinked in a bidimensional array, but they can't have two different types of data, i think. I hope someone can help me.

```
/* This is the array, cartas is cards in spanish */
for(i = 0 ; i < 52 ; i++) {
    cartas[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: Have the array be of type `char*`!? Use a `struct`!? -_-

Comment: Agreed with Dima. I.e., Make cartas hold a struct with two members--one member would be cartas.name, the other cartas.i.

Comment: Don't store the names at all. Just look up the right name when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Look up or generate the name of the card whenever you need it - no need to store it with the index:

```
char buffer[32];
int cnum = card % 13;
const char* suits[]={"diamonds", "spades", "clubs", "hearts"};
switch(cnum)
{
    case 0:
        strcpy(buffer, "ace");
        break;
    case 10:
        strcpy(buffer, "jack");
        break;
    case 11:
        strcpy(buffer, "queen");
        break;
    case 12:
        strcpy(buffer, "king");
        break;
    default:
        sprintf(buffer,"%d",cnum+1);
        break;
}
strcat(buffer," of ");
strcat(buffer,suits[card / 13]);
```

Comment: `itoa()` is non-standard, and in fact doesn't exist on a lot of systems. You can use `sprintf(buffer, "%s", cnum+1)`. But representing, e.g., the 5 of spades with the number `6` is bound to cause confusion. I'd use `1` for Ace, `2` for 2, ..., `13` for king.

Comment: Fair point on use of `itoa`, though it should be `%d` and not `%s`. The other point is just a matter of adding 1 after the modulo, rather than a few lines later, which I think is just a matter of taste - the cards are still represented by the same index regardless. I've left it, but the anyone else might want to do it a different way.

Comment: You're right, it should be `%d`. (Too bad I can't edit the comment.)